# Composing F-Algebra[F, A] to F-Algebra[F, Seq[A]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, shapeless, category-theory, scala-cats

I'm trying to compose F-Algebras like in [this page](https://japgolly.blogspot.com.br/2017/12/practical-awesome-recursion-ch-02.html). The difference is that, instead of composing with a tuple, like this:

```
type FAlgebra[F[_], A] = F[A] => A

def algebraZip[F[_], A, B](fa: FAlgebra[F, A], fb: FAlgebra[F, B])
                      (implicit F: Functor[F]): FAlgebra[F, (A, B)] =
  fab => {
    val a = fa(fab.map(_._1))
    val b = fb(fab.map(_._2))
    (a, b)
  }
```

I would like to use a `Seq`, like this:

```
def algebraSeq[F[_], A](fa: FAlgebra[F, A])
                       (implicit F: Functor[F]): FAlgebra[F, Seq[A]] = ???
```

Is it possible? What would I need? Or would using shapeless `HList` help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I can make some slight alterations to your constraints, I can find an implementation:

```
def algebraSeq[F[_]: Traverse, A](fa: FAlgebra[F, A]): FAlgebra[F, Seq[A]] = 
  fseq => fseq.sequence.map(f => fa(f))
```

I needed the `Traverse` instance to be able to sequence a `F[Seq[A]]` to a `Seq[F[A]]`.

In the past you had to write this function for `List` instead of `Seq` because there was no `Applicative[Seq]` instance. But since cats 2.3.0 instances for `immutable.Seq` (which is the default `scala.Seq` in Scala 2.13) were added.

Answer (score 3):

Completely agree with Jasper's answer. But I like to generalise ;)

The shape of your algebra is like CoKleisli:

```
  import cats._
  import cats.implicits._
  import cats.data.Cokleisli
  type FAlgebra[F[_], A] = Cokleisli[F, A, A]

  def nestEffect[F[_], A, B, G[_]](coKleisli: Cokleisli[F, A, B])
                            (implicit F: Traverse[F], G: Applicative[G]): Cokleisli[F, G[A], G[B]] =
    Cokleisli((fga: F[G[A]]) => F.sequence[G, A](fga).map(coKleisli.run))

    def algebraSeq[F[_], A](fa: FAlgebra[F, A])
                         (implicit F: Traverse[F]): FAlgebra[F, List[A]] = 
      nestEffect[F, A, A, List](fa)
```

Comment: While I like generalized versions, I chose @Jasper-M answer because I am still too new to category theory and I need some more time to digest your answer. His answer goes straight to the point, has a good explanation why he did it that way and I can just continue my work ;)

Comment: I too agree with your choice :)